# Async Task requires non-array return object from doInBackground but finds array of object

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask, android-studio

I have the following object setup like so and pass in info to an Async task:

```
DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo passCoreInfo = new DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo();
passCoreInfo.setId(1);
passCoreInfo.setAttr("C3P0");
passCoreInfo.setMethodCallType("Get Info");

new DynamoDBManagerTask()
        .execute(passCoreInfo);
```

However, despite being passed in as an object it then somehow gets converted to CoreInfo[], but the return expects CoreInfo according to my error. I've tried changing the return type for doInBackground and AsyncTask to ArrayList so it'll expect an array, but it still expects CoreInfo and not CoreInfo[] at the `return coreInfo` line.

```
private class DynamoDBManagerTask extends
            AsyncTask<DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo, Void, DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo> {
        List<DynamoDBManager.Info1> info1Result = new ArrayList<DynamoDBManager.Info1>();
        List<DynamoDBManager.Info2> info2Result = new ArrayList<DynamoDBManager.Info2>();

        protected DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo doInBackground(
                DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo... coreInfo) {

            //If coreInfo[0].getMethodCallType.equals("Get Info"),  info1Result = call DynamoDB query 1
            //Else  info2Result = call DynamoDB query 2

            return coreInfo; // Should remain untouched, same info as when passed in
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo coreInfo) {

            //If coreInfo[0].getMethodCallType.equals("Get Info"), save info1Result to SQLite table 1
            //Else save info2Result to SQLite table2            
        }
    }
```

How can I fix my code so that the types line up? And it doesn't throw the Required: CoreInfo Found: CoreInfo[] error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `DynamoDBManager.CoreInfo...` is a varargs argument, meaning you can pass multiple `CoreInfo` objects in as separate arguments and they get converted into an array. You have to return an element of that array, such as `coreInfo[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do `return coreInfo[0]`

However, if you never change `coreInfo` what's the reason to pass it? Keep it outside your `AsyncTask` or as a field in your `AsyncTask`

Comment: Because the DynamoDBManagerTask class's execution gets called in another class/.java file so it doesn't make sense to set up something like setting global variables in the .java file where DynamoDBManagerTask is defined from the other .java file.

Comment: You can create a constructor DynamoDBManagerTeask(CoreInfo ci) and so you will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Note the three dots (`...`) in the method signature of `doInBackground`. That's where your arguments will get transformed to an array.

As an example, take the following code and notice the difference in the console output below the code:

```
package box.sand;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printStrings("foo", "bar");
        printStrings("baz");
        printStringsLooped("foo", "bar");
        printStringsLooped("baz");
    }

    public static void printStrings(String... strings) {
        System.out.println(strings);
    }

    public static void printStringsLooped(String... strings) {
        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5c3a5635
[Ljava.lang.String;@79f1e0e0
foo
bar
foo
```

If you are sure only one object will be passed in to 'doInBackground', you can simply return the first object of the array (that is, `return coreInfo[0]`).